# Why is expressjs sending Set-Cookie header with every OPTIONS response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, passport.js

I've observed that my express server sends a `Set-Cookie` header in response to every `OPTIONS` request made by my front-end Angular.js project.

The cookie has a new value on each of the `OPTIONS` requests, but is never actually stored by 
Chrome.

When I use passport.js to authenticate a user, the response to the `POST` request has the same header (again with a new cookie), but this time I can see that it is stored, and sent with subsequent requests in the `Cookie` header.

Which express module is doing this, and why? And why does Chrome not store the cookie?

This is more curiosity than anything, as it's not causing any problems (just caused a lot of confusion when trying to track one down).

Comment: Are you using cookie sessions?

Comment: @Sean - what more are you looking for here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method OPTIONS are not supposed to have a side-effect. See this HTTP 1.1 [documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

OPTIONS is a request for information to the server. Such request is not considered as real interaction between a user and server. The server likely makes the information available to all users.

The browser respects this and chooses to ignore the cookies, conforming to the specification. That said it is security risk passing cookie data to user openly. Even if it is not valid, it can reveal server-side internals, which can allow hackers to exploit it.

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure this is a bug with the current session module. if you're using the new cookies session, then you won't hit this problem. feel free to file a bug: https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: Hmm. Asked two questions, got two answers. I'm going with the other, but I think yours is correct too.